# Why did Preethi leave Arjun Reddy's house without meeting him?

Tags: plot-explanation, arjun-reddy

When Preethi's father doesn't accept their relationship, Arjun Reddy gives Preethi 6 hours to decide what she wants to do or else he's out.

Preethi's dad confiscates her phone so she goes to Arjun's house. Arjun's brother spots her, they share a word and she returns home.

Why did she leave Arjun Reddy's house without meeting him?

I don't know the movie language and was watching with English subtitles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preethi comes to Arjun's home to meet Arjun Reddy and inform about her family's plans to marry her with another guy.

She is recognized by Arjun's brother and asks what happened. She asks him to convey the message to Arjun that she has come and waits for Arjun. In the meantime, Preethi's relatives come to take her back to home. They take her home. This is the reason she didn't talk with Arjun Reddy. Besides, Arjun was not in a position to talk with her as he fell unconscious in his room.

The actual dialogue was not shown in the film but by understanding the scene and the conversation between Preethi and Arjun in the climax of the movie helps to know this.

Comment: This (the plot, not your answer) doesn't make any sense. If Preeti knew she would be married off in 2 days, why would she go back to her house without getting an answer from Arjun. And why would she marry the other guy & leave him in 3 days. It's not like she was forcefully dragged by a bunch of people from Arjun's house. It makes no sense.Anyway

Comment: @KharoBangdo She was forcefully dragged away. She's born in an orthodox family & her family put many restrictions. So, she went to her home with fear on hisdad. She thought Arjun knew about her marriage and didn't come to save her due to ego. Arjun's bro came to say about news but didn't convey to him as he was unconscious. So, she married other guy. This is said in the climax conversation. She feels sorry for that.